Error when connecting to Azure SQL DataBase with PYODBC and ODBC Connection using DSN
I'm using python in a project, in which I query data from an Azure SQL Database, and then write back the results to that same database.
I use the following code to create the SQLAlchemy engine:
connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@dsn'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

When running a query, I then get this error:
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)
What puzzles me is that:

The issue only arises on our stg database, dev and prd work fine
I thought it might be special characters in the password, but other environments have the same type of characters and no issue
The dsn parameters are identical, and the stg dsn connection is used by other software, succesfully
Using the connection_url = sqlalchemy.URL.create() method with the host and database specified directly works on stg. So the database can be reached in Python. However, for reasons specific to our system and this project, I have to use the example method above with dsn.

Any idea what the issue could be? It looks like it has something to do with the stg dsn configuration, but since it looks to be the same as the other environments, I have no idea what the problem could be.

After some in-depth research, I figured out that a character or character combination in the password was causing the issue. There are two options to solve the issue:

You can either edit the password(s); or
I found this solution here:

Writing a connection string when password contains special characters
Thank you to @rcoder
In my case:
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote_plus


dbtype = 'mssql+pyodbc://'
user = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'
dsn = 'mydsn'

connection_string = dbtype + user + ':' + quote_plus(password) + '@' + dsn

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

...

engine.dispose()


Note, as per the original post, spaces in the password might cause issues with this method. All other special characters, in my case, were handled correctly and the connection worked.

(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

The issue may be with the connection string format. You can use the connection string below:
odbc_str = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;UID='+username+';DATABASE='+ database + ';PWD='+ password
connect_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_str)

It will connect to the Azure SQL database successfully without any error. Here is the complete code for your reference:
import urllib
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

sql_query = 'SELECT  * FROM [dbo].[ticker]'
server = '<serverName>.database.windows.net'
database = '<databaseName>'
username = '<userName>'
password = '<password>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
odbc_str = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;UID='+username+';DATABASE='+ database + ';PWD='+ password
connect_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_str)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_str)
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine)
print(df)

You will get the output as below for the above code:



id
name




100
Ticker 1


200
Ticker 2


300
Ticker 3


400
Ticker 4




I specifically need to use the first connection string in the original code example. And the issue is not the string format itself, since it works on 2/3 of my environments.
The proposition you made already works for me, but the scope of my project requires me to work with DSN and the OBDC connection created on the VM.
